# Clojure Collatz Conjecture NullPointerException

Tags: recursion, clojure, collatz

I keep getting a NullPointerException for the following code and I have tried and tried to trace it but to no avail. I'm trying to print out each number of a collatz conjecture which it does print out, then gives me a null pointer exception error and I can't find it.
Thanks in advance!

```
      1 (ns collatz.core
       2   (:gen-class))
       3 
       4 
       5 (defn collatz [n]
       6   (
       7    (println n)
       8     (if (= n 1)
       9       (println "done")
      10       (if (odd? n)
      11        (collatz
      12          (+(* n 3) 1))
      13        (collatz (/ n 2))))))

  14 (defn -main []  (collatz 48))



Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException, compiling:(/private/var/folders/yh/80f0k44s19lgzck9bgpq746w0000gn/T/form-init1027767069879550093.clj:1:125)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7391)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7317)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:275)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:277)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:277)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:308)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)
    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at collatz.core$collatz.invokeStatic(core.clj:6)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invoke(core.clj:5)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invokeStatic(core.clj:13)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invoke(core.clj:5)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invokeStatic(core.clj:13)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invoke(core.clj:5)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invokeStatic(core.clj:13)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invoke(core.clj:5)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invokeStatic(core.clj:13)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invoke(core.clj:5)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invokeStatic(core.clj:11)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invoke(core.clj:5)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invokeStatic(core.clj:13)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invoke(core.clj:5)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invokeStatic(core.clj:11)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invoke(core.clj:5)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invokeStatic(core.clj:13)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invoke(core.clj:5)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invokeStatic(core.clj:13)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invoke(core.clj:5)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invokeStatic(core.clj:13)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invoke(core.clj:5)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invokeStatic(core.clj:13)
    at collatz.core$collatz.invoke(core.clj:5)
    at collatz.core$_main.invokeStatic(core.clj:14)
    at collatz.core$_main.invoke(core.clj:14)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:375)
    at user$eval5.invokeStatic(form-init1027767069879550093.clj:1)
    at user$eval5.invoke(form-init1027767069879550093.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6917)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `(println n)` in the head position (line 7), which means you attempt to invoke a function value returned by `(println n)`. `println` always returns `nil`, so you get `NullPointerException`.

The minimal change is to use a `do` block:

```
(defn collatz [n]
   (do
     (println n)
     (if (= n 1)
       (println "done")
       (if (odd? n)
         (collatz
          (+ (* n 3) 1))
         (collatz (/ n 2))))))
```

Although frankly it looks unnatural in Clojure. A more idiomatic way of coding this would be producing a sequence instead of printing the elements out.

Additionally, I strongly suspect you have no need in `gen-class`. If you just need to run your function, use REPL.

*Edit:* As pointed out in the comments, the really minimal change would be removing the redundant parens, since `defn` (and `fn`) includes implicit `do`

```
(def collatz [n]
  (println n)
  (if (= n 1)
    (println "done")
    (if (odd? n)
      (collatz
       (+ (* n 3) 1))
      (collatz (/ n 2)))))
```

Comment: The minimal change would be to remove the erroneous parenthesis after the argument list, as `defn` has an implicit `do`.

Comment: @TerjeD.- you're right. I so rarely need this (for debugging printouts only) that I forgot about it.